# Geometry Nodes - Curve To Point - Rotation Problem

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, properties

If I have one dot, it becomes a problem. but when there is more than one point due to the distance, it is difficult to rotate.emphasized text

[image]

[Video For Question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q--zieOQuQ0)
[Blend File Download](https://s2.dosya.tc/server25/ps1el3/BAHCE_DUVARI.zip.html)
[image]

Comment: You also draw a vertical wall together with your points. Maybe sample nearest surface's normal and align euler to that?

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: I added blend file @chris

Comment: can u pls use https://blend-exchange.com/ and just make your blend file smaller so that it fits? it should be very easy to do that. And i tried 3 times to download your file on that turkish site (i am sorry that i don't speak turkish) but i had no idea where i had to click to download it. Or pls try to find a site which at least provides an english overview so that we can understand it  - thx.

Comment: try putting the align Euler to vector after the rotate Euler

Answer (score 1):

When you delete curve endpoints, leaving only one point, the single point no longer has a tangent to align to.

Altering your setup as little as possible, one way round this would be to store the tangent on the curve's points while they all still have one, and *then* delete the endpoints:

[image]

.. and align to the stored tangent.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, You solved this problem.